# how to convert %20 to space in Iphone SDK

Tags: nsurl

I am working on app, in which I interacting with web-service most of time. I am getting problem when I added space on somewhere it convert space to %20 when converting url to request. I googled but couldn't find any healthy solution according to my requirement because its only changing when url to request. Here is what I am doing.

```
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSLog(@"Request is : %@", request);
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and on `NSLog` it show me %20 where ever space is given. If someone know kindly suggest me better way to solve this issue. This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do u want to remove it? it called url encoding, its required for url requests/ interacting with web services.. do u want to remove this %20 from the response?

Comment: It's question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107303/file-name-nsstring-adds-unnecessary-20-in-space

Comment: @vishy because I am getting same response from webservice with "%20", so how can I deal with it?

Comment: @josh i think u got the solution now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using following line after getting response from web service.

```
 responseString= [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
```

Now I getting correct data but I think this not a good solution :).
Thanks for you answer posts.

Comment: Yes, `-stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is a better choice

Answer (score 5):

You are actually converting spaces to %20 with this instruction:

`url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

But this is necessary in order to get the correct `NSURLRequest`, as some characters need this conversion.

You can reconvert them to "normal" characters using this other `NSString` method:

[– stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:)

Answer (score 3):

**To Remove %20 from URL**

```
url = [strFileName stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want %20 instead of space then why are you using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`?

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` - converts space to %20